# Excel basic timestamp using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a very basic excel workbook for my own personal record, and what I'm wanting to do is having a record timestamp(in column B) whenever I add/edit the value of column A. As I've never dealt with VBA before, but with other programming languages, can someone point me into a right direction to start with?

I'm thinking of opening the macros to write a sub, then using a for loop to screen the whole columns and set the timestamp using TODAY() by seeing which cells in colA have been changed. But I reckon this will be a very inefficient method (as whole worksheet screening is required), I wonder what's the proper way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, L As Long, r As Range, rInt As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set rInt = Intersect(A, Target)
    If rInt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rInt
            r.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Works like a charm thank you so much Gary's student.

Comment: @ChunfaatJonathanNgai ________________You are quite welcome! ___________